# Circuit goes mad when programming the arduino

Tags: arduino, power-supply, transistors

So, I have a circuit with an arduino. Connected to the arduino there's an IR sensor, an LCD screen, a little servo motor, a MCP23017 expander with the A register to control a l239D and the B register for status leds and button inputs. On the other side I have two dc motor connected to the l239d and powered by an external power supply. The arduino and the external power supply are common grounded.

Here's the problem, when I program the arduino the circuit start to be totally crazy, lcd start to flickr, servo too and motors runs at 100% speed. I had this behaviour at runtime too but it was solved when I placed caps on the the two l239d power inputs and one on each dc motor wires (+ and -).

Until now when I was programming the arduino the external power supply was turned off. But now I need it to be on when the arduino setup method is called. And I don't have psychic power to guess exactly when that could happend so I can't turn it on a the right moment...

I'm looking for a solution cause for now the arduino have survived but I'm pretty sure things will go really wrong (I'm in the software industry and Murhpy is my good ol' friend...)

What can I do to avoid that behaviour ? Is a transistor to control from the arduino the external power supply connected to the l239d enough ?

Comment: Do you use TX/RX pins?

Comment: I program I through the usb port and use serial through usb too. So I don't directly the TX/RX D0/D1 pins.

Comment: I asked you do you use Pin 0 or Pin 1 cause they are TX/RX pins used to read serial data you are sending ( and receiving ) through USB and If you put an LED on pin 0 ( RX ) and GND when you try to program your Arduino the LED will flicker. :)

Comment: But but that don't solve my problem I think, or I've missed something :/

Comment: Why can't you have the external power on all the time?

Comment: Is it a problem that it flickers? I have one board with a shift-register RGB LED driver and it makes the LED flicker when programming.

Comment: Oh If you use shift register, that shift register probably doesn't have a latch pin. Making an LED to flicker... I would suggest using another shift register that does have a latch pin.

Comment: The problem is clearly described in the question. The issue here is that when the arduino is being programmed I got voltage from my external power supply goeing across the entire circuit so I would like to control when the l239d external supply is on. But I've found a solution by using a transistor with a a diode to avoid forward voltage on the 4 ground of the l239d.

Comment: Then you use a transistor... Don't really know whats the problem. Always try before asking.

Comment: Try ?! What the... Always try before asking ? You mean evaluate solutions I hope ? I got around 150€ of components on the actual board and I should "Try" to not blow them before asking ? We're not in software development here, the result is not just a little exception saying "hey it's wrong dude". I asked for solutions but as you don't seem to offers some I had to pick my first choice, until someone could offer me a better or more appropriate solution than a transistor. And also I'm not sure that it really solve the problem. But thank you for the TX/RX leds, really useful and on-topic...

Comment: @Emmanuel Istace Can you post an actual schematic of how everything is connected?

Comment: @EmmanuelIstace One of my personal tenets in electronic design: If you don't burn stuff you don't learn stuff :-)

Comment: @AndrejaKo : Yes but it can take a long time as the circuit is already pretty complex. What do you want to know exactly ?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh : Yes but in that case I really can't, it's my girlfriend christmas gift (she asked me for an autonomous robot with ir commands, setup of a custom message on the lcd screen and a solar panel to reload his battery) and I'm already late on it (thank you procrastination) so I really can't blow anything as I will not have the time to buy new parts...

Comment: -1 for complaining about suggestions based on incomplete information. As @looky said, it's not clear what your problem is. If the system "goes mad" _while_ programming, who cares? How can you expect us to know _exactly_ what part of the schematic we need to see?

Comment: @Emmanuel Istace Well if you have a pretty complex circuit and no schematic, then you're doing it wrong. Also you seem to be concerned about your investment in components. A  great way to burn components is to work without a schematic. What I want to know specifically is exactly how each components is connected and by that I mean what is connected to every pin of every component. A schematic will contain that information which is essential part of the design process.

Comment: Without that and a list of pin states in (at least) every major state of the circuit, you can't expect to be able to safely construct a board. Whatever your issue is, it's probably something very simple, but it will require effort to detect it. To be able to do that, you'll need to have a clear image of how everything works in your mind as well as on paper and you need to be able to quickly and efficiently check if your idea is closely related to the reality. Often just a few bad connections can make big problems.

Comment: It's not easy to do all this and I understand that you're under pressure, but there really is no other way to help you other than being lucky and randomly pointing at an issue which happens to be the main problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **What can I do to avoid that behaviour ?**

During programming, isolate the pins used for programming from the rest of your circuit.
During normal operation, reconnect those pins to the rest of your circuit.

[image]
[image]
[image]

<sup>*Example from Arduino MIDI shield*</sup>